# Are there any options to control Schema Validation in 5.4? Specifically, sequence allocationSize validation

Tags: hibernate

I just upgraded from Hibernate 5.1 to Hibernate 5.4.18
(Needed to upgrade due to a hibernate JOIN ON issue).

After upgrading, my program is now failing validation because the allocationSize does not match the database (postgres11) sequence increment_by value.

In my situation, the increment_by value in the database is not always the same, depending on the installation.

My class looks roughly like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="my_table_seq", name="my_table_seq")
public class MyTable implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_table_seq")
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    etc...
```

The resulting error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
Schema-validation: sequence [my_table_seq] defined inconsistent increment-size; found [20] but expecting [50]
```

I know that the 50 is coming from the hibernate defaults for SequenceGenerator, and that I could just set the allocationSize to be 20.

However, as noted, my sequence increment_by values in the database are not always the same across installations, which is due to various database replication configurations.

Looking at this code:
[Validator code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/shawnz/8f7308741e2ff6270cc8878ac69b4f6b)
I have discovered that I can set the allocationSize to be zero or -1, which will prevent validation, but I am not sure if that will have other unintended consequences.

Another option is to turn off schema validation for production databases, I suppose, but I would rather not do that.

I guess another option is to update all the production databases to have an increment with the lowest common denominator.  Looking back, I can see myself saying something like "I wonder why the default increment is 50?  That's weird."

Thanks for any ideas!